# Using the webBrowser control to show google map directions

Tags: winforms, google-maps

I'm using google maps to show directions inside a web browser control, and suddenly my windows xp users are reporting there is no longer a line following the roads. Also, it draws a shaded shape on the map (showing a territory) and this no longer works. Did google change something? Can I still support this?

Comment: I'd make other plans if I were you. The WebBrowser control is effectively another browser that is a subset of IE. I'd guess the Maps developers don't even bother to test this platform so you can expect some features to fade away over time. I'd also guess MS isn't trying to trying to keep IE and the control on semi-equal footing. You might have better luck with a Chromium control, but IMO the better bet would just to be to launch the default browser on the client.

Comment: That's about what I expected to hear.

Comment: See [Issue 9004: Issue 9004: Bug: Javascript error](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9004) (MS defaults the browser control to a no longer supported version of IE)